# Decoupling Backbone views where one triggers change in other view

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views

I have a page which contains two Backbone Views. A view for list of contacts **ContactsListView** and a view for navigating **NavView**.
ContactsListView has **collection of Contact models**. My list of contacts collections is quite bigger so I don’t want to display all of them on page load.

So I have implemented contacts collection to fetch only **a range** (initially 0 to 50) of contacts from server and ContactsListView displays it. And use NavView to display the range of contacts ContactsListView is displaying **currently**. It also has **next and previous buttons** on click of which ContactsListView should display next or previous range of contacts.

Here my NavView is actually **controlling** what range of contacts ContactsListView should be displaying. But I want to decouple ContactsListView from NavView.

I realized I can do this with creating a **Range model** (with from and to attributes with default set to 0 and 50) and passing it to ContactsListView and NavView. While ContactsListView adds a listener, ***ContactsListView.show(from, to)***, to change event on Range model and NavView is updating the Range model when clicked on next or previous button. As the Range model changes ContactsListView listener would fetch contacts to update it's view.

Or

I can create a Range model and pass it to NavView. NavView then updates the range on click of prev or next button and triggers an event **rangeUpdated** with range values on (NavView) itself.  I add **listener on NavView** in some additional code piece (probably my own controller object) and invoke ContactsListView.show(from, to) **explicitly**.

Which one is better way to decouple ContactsListView and NavView? Or is there other way to decouple them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your question is tagged with backbone.marionette, I assume you are using it, or thinking about using it.

One option could be using the [**marionette.compositeview**](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.compositeview.md), that lets you define **both a model and a collection in the same view**, so you wouldn't need to share models between views.

But maybe, that **could not the best approach if you really want to decouple both views**. For decoupling them, your second option using your own controller (or [**marionette.controller**](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.controller.md)) is the one I like more, as you don't need the range number as explicit data contained in a model within the ContactListView (you already have that information in NavView).

Lastly, I like to do the **fetching/saving data from the Controller, and not from within the view**. The View in MVC patterns just show things, getting information from the model. Retrieving data from server that will be stored in the model seems more a **Controller** operation. I don't know how are you binding the data with the view, but maybe the ideal will be fetching the data from the Controller, and let the view render itself when the change of model is detected.

Comment: Right, I don't want my `ContactListView` to maintain the `Range` model in it, it has it's own Contacts collection to represent. Range is being just a ui entity, does not hold business model literally, So I think I shouldn't create `Range` model as such.

Comment: And yes I’m evaluating backbone.marionette too. So marionette.controller can actually fetch the contacts from server to update the contacts collection. While ContactListView will update itself listening to add events on contacts collection.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize both views with Range model.
In Contact List view listen to Range model change event to request new data from Contacts collection and show them.
When click on Nav view just set the Range model with new values (it will trigger change event and your Contact List view will be updated).

Comment: Thanks Eugene. I think If I have not tried hands with Backbone.Marionette, I might not have confused. I thought of making `ContactListView` to just display contacts and not to worry what range of contacts to fetch and show. Something else directing `ContactsListView` by changing the Contacts collection. View being just display what it has.